# only one user able to edit record after submit the approval process

Tags: approval-process

We are using one customobject and we created approval process on that object
Here we have 10 users like userA,userB,C.....etc with same proile, In this only 1 user(userB) is able to edit all records after submit approval process
those records are lastmodified by raja(He is also having same profile and same role) and remaing user try to edit records but they get record lock error. 
userB dosn't have a permission set,Role also same to all and what are records 
Here my requirement is we don't want to give edit permission for userB and we want show record lock error for userB.
Can any one help me on this issue.

Comment: Can you edit your question and specify the use case properly.

Comment: Is the user that has edit permission on the record also the assigned approver in the approval process?